# Include nesting factor as fixed effect in a GLMM

Tags: r, fixed-effects-model, glmm, nested-data

I have the following GLMM:

```
success ~ age + gender + group/task + (1 + group/task|school/subject), family = binomial
```

I want to know whether participants' probability to succeed in certain problem-solving tasks can be predicted by the type of task. 
I have 6 tasks which can be categorized into 3 groups (A, B, C) with 2 tasks in each group. Each participant received 3 tasks (one from A, one from B, one from C; combination and order counterbalanced).
Cochran's Q- and post-hoc McNemar tests revealed that the three groups differ in their success rates: A is easier than B and C, and B and C are equally difficult.
I used crosstabs to analyze whether the tasks within each group differ in their success rates and found that they are different for A and B.

Now I would like to do a comparison of all individual tasks (not just those within one category).

My question is: Is the equation above correct in terms of the fixed effects or is there any reason to include group as an extra fixed effect (e.g. to see whether task has an effect on top of the group effects found in the McNemar tests)? Would that be unnecessary?

What does it mean to include both group/task and group?

Comment: what does the `group\task` mean in the equation? The equation as it's written is confusing. You don't mention the `school\subject`. Which package you intend to use?

Comment: Hi Steve, group\task is meant to be "task nested within group". This is as far as I know the way it is written in R. The school/subject means that my study subjects are nested within schools. What else is confusing? Sorry about that. I intend to use lme4 in R.

Comment: So the \ is actually a /. Right?

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry. I just edited the post.

Comment: I really don't know what should I answer first, its seems that you haven't read anything regarding the `lme4` package, you should be able to answer your questions by reading even the manual of the package. In addition, I would suggest you have a look at http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/ . Your equation is wrong, but for more reasons than the one you ask. If you edit it a lot I could provide an answer, but it needs at least some basis of argument.

Comment: Hello Steve, I have indeed read quite some literature and also run GLMMs before that have been checked by statisticians. Would you mind telling me, at least briefly, why you think the equation is wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's try to simulate some data with a similar structure of your problem's data. My understanding from your description is that we have something like this:

Say we have 4 schools with 8 subjects in each school, thus a total of 32 subjects. 
Each subject is posed with 3 tasks (one from each group), thus a total of 96 observations. As we have 6 different tasks, we will ask 16 times each task (6*16=96), so 32 tasks from each group (32*3=96).

```r
n.schools <- 2
n.subject <- 20
n         <- n.subject*3
subject   <- rep(1:n.subject, 3)
school    <- rep(1:n.schools, (n/n.schools))

age    <- rnorm(n.subject, 30, 5)
age    <- rep(age,3)
gender <- sample(c(0,1),n.subject, replace=TRUE)
gender <- rep(gender,3)

A     <- c(rep(1,n/3),rep(0,2*n/3))
B     <- c(rep(0,n/3),rep(1,n/3), rep(0, n/3))
C     <- c(rep(0,2*n/3),rep(1,n/3))
group <- c(rep("A",n/3), rep("B",n/3),rep("C",n/3))
task  <- c(rep("a",n/6),rep("b",n/6),rep("c",n/6),rep("d",n/6),rep("e",n/6),rep("f",n/6))

u.subject <- rnorm((n/3), 0, 1)
u.school  <- rnorm(n.schools, 0 ,1)

lattent <- -20 + 0.5*age + 2*gender + 2*A -3*B -3.2*C + u.subject + u.school + rnorm(n,0,1)
pr      <- 1/(1+exp(-lattent))
success <- rbinom(n, 1, pr)
```

Now let's try a GLMM model as the one you propose:

```
library(lme4)
> glmer(success ~ age + gender + group/task + (1 + group/task | school/subject), family=binomial)
Error: number of observations (=60) < number of random effects (=360) 
for term (1 + group/task | subject:school); 
the random-effects parameters are probably unidentifiable
```

So what does this mean? In general, you need your mixed effects model to be identifiable, and one of the conditions for this to happen is $\sum_{i=1}^N (n_i-k) >0$, where $k$ is the number of random effects. In the case of balanced data, this can be written equivalently $N n_1 > N k$ or $n_1 > k$. In other words you need to have less random parameters than the number of observations in each cluster/group, subject in your case. This cannot be the case if you add the `group/task` term in the random part.

**What `group/task` or `school/subject` means in the formula?**

This is simply an equivalent way of writing `group + group:task` so you actually have `group` and its interaction with `task`. So the last question doesn't actually makes sense. The same principle is used when you put this term as a grouping factor in the right part of `(1 | ...)` which actually translates to `(1| school) + (1 | school:subject)` hence the one factor nested within the other.

So, I suggest you read [Chapter 2 from Bates book](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/lMMwR/lrgprt.pdf#page=43) and pay extra attention to [model specification](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq#toc27). It is really important to define what actually makes sense to include as fixed or random effects and what the grouping factors will be. This depends on how you designed the study and what you want to extract from your models.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, Steve.I thought by modelling group/task I would tell the program that I have a nested structure, as it is the case with school and subject. I will read Bates' chapter and might come back to here if I have further questions. Thanks a lot for your help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use them too as grouping factor, just be carefull about the levels and the structure of the random effects. If you think this answer helps and answers your question you can vote up and accept it.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Unfortunately I can't vote answers up yet (not enough reputation).

Comment: Thanks a gain for your help. I was wondering how I calculate the number of random effects in my model. So in your example, how do you get to the 360?

Comment: I read Bates' chapter and I see what he is doing with the random intercepts for nested variables, but the chapter does not cover random slopes for nested factors.? Is it theoretically - leaving aside for a moment the question of whether the model is identifiable - possible to include a random slope for a nested factor? For theoretical and empirical reasons I want to include a random slope for task on subject. And since task is nested within group, I thought I had to include it in the random effects structure as well. So, do I understand correctly that the "only" wrong thing in the ...

Comment: ...model is the fact that it is not identifiable?

Comment: In general, you add a random intercept for each cluster, if you have a variable which varies as well, you can include it in the model as a random slope. But again, be careful of the levels of your random effects.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. What exactly is it that I have to be careful about? I know that "task" has 6 levels. Where is the pitfall here?

Comment: The nested factors! If you put them as nested of course. Anyways, this discussion is way too long for comments' area in CV, sorry.